# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getTransportChannel() called when needsExecutor() is true while using bigquery client library in dataflow

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-api-java-client

Due to some criteria I need to write some entries to a specific table using bigquery client library  in my dataflow job, I can query a table using bq client library without any issue but when I try to write into the table I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) on project <project name>: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.IllegalStateException: getTransportChannel() called when needsExecutor() is true -> [Help 1]
```

Below is the full error

```
[org.##.addg.gcp.##.main()] INFO org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner - PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 220 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
[WARNING]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getTransportChannel() called when needsExecutor() is true
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.newBigQueryWriteClient (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1262)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.access$800 (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:134)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.<init> (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:523)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.<init> (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:451)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.getDatasetService (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead.validate (BigQueryIO.java:985)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$ValidateVisitor.enterCompositeTransform (Pipeline.java:662)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:581)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500 (TransformHierarchy.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:214)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically (Pipeline.java:469)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.validate (Pipeline.java:598)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:322)
    at org.##.addg.gcp.##.main (##.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getTransportChannel() called when needsExecutor() is true
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel (InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:204)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create (ClientContext.java:205)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.stub.GrpcBigQueryWriteStub.create (GrpcBigQueryWriteStub.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.stub.BigQueryWriteStubSettings.createStub (BigQueryWriteStubSettings.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.BigQueryWriteClient.<init> (BigQueryWriteClient.java:128)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.BigQueryWriteClient.create (BigQueryWriteClient.java:109)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.newBigQueryWriteClient (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1257)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.access$800 (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:134)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.<init> (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:523)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.<init> (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:451)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl.getDatasetService (BigQueryServicesImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead.validate (BigQueryIO.java:985)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$ValidateVisitor.enterCompositeTransform (Pipeline.java:662)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:581)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500 (TransformHierarchy.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit (TransformHierarchy.java:214)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically (Pipeline.java:469)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.validate (Pipeline.java:598)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:322)
    at org.##.addg.gcp.##.main (##.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.009 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-17T10:55:59Z
```

The line 125 of main class just has the piepline.run(options).waitUntilFinish() statement
Here's the code that I'm running

```
public class ## {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        
        PCollection<TableRow> orders = pipeline
                .apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery("query").usingStandardSql());
        
        PCollection<TableRow> customers = pipeline
                .apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery("query").usingStandardSql());
        
        PCollection<Long> count = customers.apply(Count.globally());
        PCollectionView<Long> countView = count.apply(View.asSingleton());
        
        PCollection<Void> c = count.apply(ParDo.of(new MakeCountEntryFn("processed_records", countView)).withSideInput("count", countView));
        
        PCollection<TableRow> result = customers.apply(new Join(orders, "CustomerID"));
        
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        
        TableId tableId = TableId.of("jointest", "abc");
        WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration =
                WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId).setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.json()).build();
        
        TableDataWriteChannel writer = bigquery.writer(writeChannelConfiguration);
        
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
        jsonData.put("run_id", "test");
        jsonData.put("job_status", "running");
        
        String data = String.valueOf(jsonData);
         try {
              writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));   
        } finally {
              writer.close();
        }
        
        pipeline.run(options).waitUntilFinish();

    }
    
    public static void writeToAbcTable(JSONObject jsonObject, String dataset, String table) throws IOException {
        
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        
        TableId tableId = TableId.of(dataset, table);
        WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration =
                WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId).setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.json()).build();
        
        TableDataWriteChannel writer = bigquery.writer(writeChannelConfiguration);
        
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
        jsonData.put("run_id", "test");
        jsonData.put("job_status", "running");
        
        String data = String.valueOf(jsonObject);
         try {
              writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));   
        } finally {
              writer.close();
        }
    }
    
    public static class MakeCountEntryFn extends DoFn<Long, Void>{
        
        private String countColumn;
        private PCollectionView<Long> countView;

        public MakeCountEntryFn(String countColumn, PCollectionView<Long> countView) {
            this.countColumn = countColumn;
            this.countView = countView;
        }
        
        @ProcessElement
        public void ProcessElement(ProcessContext c) {
            Long i = c.sideInput(countView);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            
            obj.put(countColumn, String.valueOf(c.element()));
            try {
                writeToAbcTable(obj, "test", "##");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what I need to change to get this code to work without that issue, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the detailed stacktrace and code. It might be good to file a Jira against Beam. I am doing a little investigation to understand the error but my immediate instinct is auth could be related (though the error doesn't look quite like that)

Comment: My other guess is conflicts between dependencies, so a version of one library is expecting a newer version of the other, or something like that.

Comment: Can you share the version of Beam and/or the full output of `mvn dependency:tree`? The line of `BigQueryIO$TypedRead.validate` does not match the current code so I want to make sure I am checking the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The failure is occurring during the validation of the configuration of the BigQueryIO connector, before running the job. The line that fails is

```
DatasetService datasetService = getBigQueryServices().getDatasetService(bqOptions);
```

Here, `bqOptions` are determined by the pipeline options you provide, which in this case come in as `args`. However, I would not expect this to cause such a failure.

My best guess is that this is a dependency conflict, where the version of the gax, gRPC, and BigQuery storage client libraries are not aligned. To eliminate this from consideration, you can use the GCP Libraries BOM (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/libraries-bom) which Beam also uses to align its GCP dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Kenn! You're a life saver. I was able to find a work around for it by downgrading the beam version to 2.25 from 2.31. Do you need the output of mvn dependency:tree?

Comment: I think if a downgrade succeeded, then it is probably dependencies, indeed. Most likely each user has to examine their dependencies themselves. What we are trying to do moving forward is to get people to use the BOM, because we test all these versions of libraries together.